# Language-independent keyboard: culturating neutral text in English -kbd without things such as umlauts?

Tags: keyboard, linguistics, semantic-analysis, dvorak, os-agnostic

I like to use US Dvorak International keyboard while programming -- every manual, every documentation and also program with it. I am driving my teachers crazy because every-now-and-then they require me to write things in different languages such as German, Finnisch, Swedish or Norwegian. I tend to get stupid decreases in grades because I am lazy to switch keyboard, missing oddities such as umlauts. I find keyboard -switching slow and I am nowadays many-times more productive Drovakist than Qwertyist.

This puzzle requires some linguistic understanding to determine the text. Does there exist any program like the point (3) or the below oneliner?

> $ culturifyIt inputMe > outputYouIwillDetectAutomaticallyYourInputOutputLanguages

**Examples**

> 'Ich heisse Henry.' >> 'Ich heiße Henry.' (Germafication)
>
> 'Tusentals soldater stor redo for ett mojligt markkrig.' >> 'Tusentals soldater står redo för ett möjligt markkrig.' (Swedification)
>
> 'Yoak.' >> 'Yöäk.' (Finification)

**Methods for Culturification**

> 1. Keyboard -switching, slow.
> 2. Specific key-combos for special characters such as umlautified o, u or a -- very platform-dependent -solution, errorsome.
> 3. ...any more automated method that would detect the language and then culturefy the text?

Comment: Keyboard switching can be relatively fast.. I'm using a standard US keyboard layout, but have mapped the capslock key to enable/disable Norwegian vowels in their regular place. If you're on windows, check out the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339)

Comment: @thebjorn thank you for the point, I meant it OS-agnostic so added the label. I am looking for a platform-independent solution.

Comment: if you're on any other platform creating a custom keyboard layout should be even easier ;-)  I'm wondering if perhaps you've misunderstood umlauts etc. they're not modifications to the base letter, but letters in their own right. If you look at a Sweedish keyboard layout (dvorak/qwerty, doesn't matter) you'll notice that `a` and `å` are on different keys.  General transliteration would require deep text analysis, and probably require you to manually verify the result (there are words where both `a` and `å` form valid words, but with entirely different semantics).

Comment: @thebjorn thank you for the point, added the label `'semantic-analysis'`.